# Where to handle promise errors in a REST api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, promise

For instance lets take a `login` flow, where a user can login with `facebook` or `email+password`, if the user logs in with `facebook` first, a `user credential + user entity` is created under that `facebook  [email + id]`.

The same user may forget they used `facebook` intially and try to create an `email` login. Now what happens is that user will have to `sign in` with the `facebook` account to be able to create the new `email credential` for the `user entity`.

Todo this I've got two classes, 1 (login_handler.js), 2 (user.js, which handles all the queries).

Inside my `user.js` class I've got:

Basically what this does is, checks if the user exists, if it exists and the userType (the type of account they're logging in with) is different to the accountType (email, facebook) in the database. I'm wondering if I should be handling this type of logic inside my promise chain (login_handler.js) or directly in the class?

```
checkUserExists () {
    console.log ("BEFORE ERROR")
    const {externalId, email, password, userType} = this;
    var query;
    if (this.userType == 'email')
      query = `select * from content_usercredential where email = '${email}' AND secret = '${password}'`;
    else if (this.userType == 'facebook'){
      query = `select * from content_usercredential where email = '${email} AND externalId = '${externalId}'`;
    }

  return new Promise ( (fulfill, reject) => {
       conn.query(query, (err, user) => {
          if (user.accountType == 'facebook' && this.userType == 'email') {
             // Should I handle this here, or in my login_handler promise chain?
             this.res.json("you must login with facbeook", session data here...so when they sign in we can pick up where we left off);
             throw new Error ("Return confirmation object to client");
       });
   });
```

login_handler.js

Should I be handling and throwing an error here so the rest of my promise chain doesn't execute, or should I be throwing an error directly where it happens (in the user.js class).

```
  User.checkUserExists()
  .then ( () => {
      // Should I handle here OR in my user.js class file?
      if (User.needsToConfirm) {
          this.res.json("you must login with facbeook", session data here...so when they sign in we can pick up where we left off);
          throw new Error("OR should I return the confirmation object here?"});
     }
  }).then( () => return createNewUserEntity())
    .then( () => return createUserCredential())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two classes have a clear responsibility. `User.js` accessing the data layer and `login_handler.js` handling login requests **and responses**.

Think of some time in the future you have to replace your data access layer (`User.js`) or your login service layer (`login_handler.js`). Changing the data layer would cause reimplementing the response and changing the service layer would cause to change the data layer because you will have to re-implement the response.

Therefore make sure your classes have always a clear responsibility and a minimal set of common interaction.

Comment: Good explanation! Clears up a couple core things!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use bluebird instead of native Promise.
(http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html)

Please follow this steps

```
const Promise = require('bluebird')

return Promise.try(() => User.checkUserExists())
  .then ( () => {
      // Should I handle here OR in my user.js class file?
      if (User.needsToConfirm) {
          this.res.json("you must login with facbeook", session data here...so when they sign in we can pick up where we left off)
          throw 'exit1'
      }
  }).then( () => return createNewUserEntity())
    .then( () => return createUserCredential()) 
    .catch(e => {
       if (e === 'exit1') {
          // your error
       }
       else {
          // system error
       }
    })
```

Comment: Good idea. I'll look into it!